# vs code - hover does not show on remote connections

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

When i work locally on vs code everything works as expected. When I hover over a variable/method usw. I can see additional information:

[image: variable correctly recognized]

vs code also recognizes variables as their respective object as I am typing:

[image: variable correctly recognized - inline]

However, when I use the remote ssh plugin this changes completely. Here is what the same things look like on my remote machine:

[image: no information on hover]

[image: object type not recognized]

can anyone tell me how to fix this? i would assume IntelliSense is not working, however I have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue as yours, then I re-install VSCode, the problem is solved.